# local mongo client can't connect to a local mongod server

Tags: mongodb

I have a `mongod` instance running on an `ubuntu` 16.04 virtual server, listening on port 27017 on the local host :

```
netstat -tulpn :

tcp        0      0      127.0.0.1:27017         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      11639/mongod
```

But a local `mongo` client script fails to connect on port 27017 :

```
MongoDB shell version v3.4.9

connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017

W NETWORK  [thread1] Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017 after 5000ms milliseconds, giving up.
E QUERY    [thread1] Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:237:13
@(connect):1:6
exception: connect failed
```

Everything is local, so AFAIK all ports are opened.

The server log just says :

> I NETWORK  [thread1] waiting for connections on port 27017

What can explain the connection failure ?

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, before you use mongo cli, you should start mongod.

```
$ sudo mongod
```

or

```
$ sudo service mongod restart
```

and check the status of mongod service

```
$ sudo service mongod status
```

then use mongo shell

```
$ mongo
```

Answer (score 0):

This a network binding issue.   Try connecting to `mongodb://localhost:27017`
Also, try commenting out the `bind_ip` param in the `mongod` startup, e.g.

```
# bind_ip = 127.0.0.1
```

Does the `mongo` CLI connect?   If so, double check the client script invocation parameters are being passed correctly.

To be extra sure the `mongod` is running, try this too:

```
$ curl 'http://localhost:27017'
It looks like you are trying to access MongoDB over HTTP on the native driver port.
```

Comment: mongo CLI doesn't connect either. commenting #bind_ip and trying the connection on localhost doesn't help.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure mongod is in fact running?   Did you try backing all the way up to two windows, starting mongod with all options exposed in the foreground in one and trying to connect via the CLI in the other?

Comment: Yes. On one window i manually  run the command : /usr/bin/mongod --port 27017 --bind_ip 127.0.0.1 --logpath /var/log/mongodb/mongodb.log --dbpath /var/lib/mongodb --logappend --fork. And on the other mongo. But still no connection. Very strange...

Comment: Try again without the --bind_ip option and without --fork.